# how to remove warnings in excel generated by POI ?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for writing content into excel sheet. after generating an excel in all the cells which ever cell has numbers, it contains one blue mark(each cells left top corner). its like a warning. how can i remove them while writing the content to excel? PFA screen shot.[image]

Thanks!

Comment: as far as I know the marker means something like "hey, this cell has an invalid format, please set it to number/...". How are you writing the Excel sheet?

Comment: Hi Matten thanks for  your reply. i am getting below message. "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an aposrophe". i am using below code. HSSFCell cell=row1.createCell(i);
  cell.setCellValue(value);  Thanks!

Comment: You are simply outputting `Numeric` values as `String Cells`, that why it's complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the cell type:

```
HSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(i);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); // =0, or Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC = 1
cell.setCellValue(value);
```

See the [API docs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#setCellType%28int%29) for more information.

Comment: It is not working. I have tried it.I have same problem.

Comment: The answer is five years old; maybe it does not apply to current versions of excel..

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me.

**

```
HSSFCell cell = row1.createCell(i);
cell.setCellType(new Double(value));
```

**

Note: 'value' should be on numerals , it won't work on alphanumeric values. 
replace it wherever(cell values) it is required.

Comment: Why are you setting the cell's value to it's type? That won't work in almost all cases!

Comment: This is wrong! who is this supposed to acutally work? should fix this post