# How to remove warning in Excel using apache poi in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `apache poi api` to generate Excel sheet in my application in java. Data that are set in excel are coming dynamically with type string. **For column1, values are alphanumeric**. When I generate Excel, it will give me green indication with warning **"Number Stored as Text"** or **"Text date with 2-digit year"** on cell.

I want to remove that warning.
I found that from excel we can flag a cell as 'ignore error', to ignore the warning.

How to do it programmatically or is there any other alternative to achieve this task ?

I also have attached screenshot that shows warning with green mark.

[image]

Code :

```
if (cellValue != null && (shouldBeRightAlign))
{
 cellType = Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC;
}
else if (cellValue != null)
{
 cellType = Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING;
}
cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
```

Comment: Cant you set the cell value with appropriate Data format like Number,Date,String,etc., ?

Comment: I have tried this also, but still not working..

Comment: @vels4j I did that but still have the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove warnings in excel generated by POI ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229644/how-to-remove-warnings-in-excel-generated-by-poi)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229852/1862502

Comment: Its not working. I checked it.

Comment: @CharveeShah share the snippet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The API now provides a corresponding method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#addIgnoredErrors(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IgnoredErrorType...))

```
public void addIgnoredErrors(CellRangeAddress region,
                    IgnoredErrorType... ignoredErrorTypes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not currently possible with Apache POI. There are a number of bug reports / RFEs on the subject:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58641

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54868

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46136

The actual attribute (the attribute that says to ignore such warning) exists in the Excel persistent format and is recorded on a per cell basis. It is just that Apache POI doesn't expose it, as far as I can tell from the bug reports.

To give you an idea of what this looks like in Excel's xlsx format:

```
</worksheet>
    ...
    <ignoredErrors>
        <ignoredError sqref="K192 E181 E186" numberStoredAsText="1"/>
    </ignoredErrors>    
</worksheet>
```

I've read somewhere that this is persisted only in `xlsx` (i.e. OOXML), not in `xls` format which means that if and when the Apache POI team implements this it will be in the XSSF package.

Comment: Apache POI actually has most of the low level support for these ignores for both HSSF and XSSF, it's just awaiting someone coming up with a sensible high-level API design, to wrap them up in a form that's more user friendly. Please contribute to the bugs if you can think of a good way to do it!

Comment: @Gagravarr. Yeah. But in OOXML it is so bloody simple that no abstraction would be needed IMHO. You would just need a new method:  `XSSFSheet.setIgnoredErrors(Set<IgnoredErrorType> x, Set<CellReference> y)` and then forget about supporting this feature in XLS format. I've added [RFE 58641](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58641) to track this.

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the solutions above worked, but at the end got rid of the warnings with a bit convoluted workaround: writting the values as formulas like this.

```
String asFormula = "\"" + value + "\"";
cell.setCellType(SXSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula(asFormula);
```

Don't think it is always a good solution, but in my case the values of the output file are never modified. But it might help somebody.

I'm using version 3.14 of apache POI, in case it makes a difference (I've tried a few different versions before the workaround, with no effect).

Comment: cell.setCellType(SXSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);

this solved my issue thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `cell type` like :

```
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

For alphanumeric and `Character` cell type will be `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING` for number, cell type will be `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`

You can get more on cell type from [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) and [HSSFCell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html) documentation.

Comment: See edited question in which I mentioned that for column1 value is alphanumeric. It may have characters or it can be only number.

Comment: But still you will get warning, his question is to remove warnings

Comment: @CharveeShah check the edited answer. you will have to check at Java side if data type is `Character` then use `CELL_TYPE_STRING` or `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` for number.

Comment: @vels4j by setting the cell type the warning will be remove.

Comment: @Vishrant data type will be always string.

Comment: @CharveeShah if you want to create a numeric type cell then you will have to parse `String` to `Integer` then set this value to cell

Comment: @Vishrant I don't know what the value is coming.For column 1 it have both.

Comment: @use `Regex` for checking if `String` is alphanumeric or number

Comment: @Vishrant if I use regex then also green indicator is shown on column5.

Comment: @CharveeShah as I can see in image of your question column5 and column6 are of same type, set type of column 5 same as column 6. You might be setting column5 type as `CELL_TYPE_STRING`

Comment: @Vishrant and what about column1??and column5 and column6 both have cell type numeric.Bt the value is in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Old one But Still it This will help Some one from .NET who use NPOI

I tried with

```
cell.SetCellType(NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.NUMERIC);
```

which didn't helped at all. but the below code will work

```
dCell.setCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(112.45)); //.NET syntax

dCell.setCellValue(new Double("123"));  // Java Syntax
```

Comment: The value is not specific that it will be numeric.It can be numeric or it can be alphanumeric.

Comment: @CharveeShah what is string then ? what purpose does CellType serve?

Comment: Values are coming from mysql query.So 1st column has both value alphanumeric or numeric only.When only numeric value comes then it shows green indicator.And for column 5 the data is coming with "," value.In that also green indicator is there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I resolved it through checking the data if it is an Integer/Float and putting the condition(CELL_TYPE) accordingly. Please find the code Snippet:

```
if(!isInteger(data))
            {
            cell.setCellValue(data);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(data));//.parseInt(data));   
            }
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        java.lang.Float.parseFloat(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here data is a String from the array of list from the data source(excel/csv)
This resolved the green warning.

Comment: I have already done that but still i was facing issue cause in data i m getting 1,00 type value with comma so it was giving me error on parseFloat method.

Comment: you can add the columns which will have integers. private  static ArrayList<Integer> intColRef = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
  {
   add(i);
  }
  }};

if(!intColRef.contains(cellNum))
{
cells.setCellValue(each);
}
else
{
cells.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cells.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(each));
}

Comment: all the values are coming dynamically only format is same. In One case it may be possible I have all the string value. or combination of values. I don't have values predefined.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time since the question was asked, but still...
Did you try this:

```
DataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("@"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Old but still relevant.

You should use "." in text as decimal separator and to format cell as NUMERIC.

Use also DataFormat with de pattern "#.00" and voila! No warning and everything gones fine.

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(data));
DataFormat format = hwb.createDataFormat();
CellStyle numbercellStyle = hwb.createCellStyle();
numbercellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#.00"));
cell.setCellStyle(numbercellStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You can also use below code in poi 4.1.1

cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(yourvalue));